# Неверное использование LIKE в запросе MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

В базе данных имеется такой список таблиц:

```
dialog_123_1
dialog_123_2
dialog_1_123456
dialog_2_1
```

Всё что после после символа _ это логины. ТО есть dialog_123_1 это диалог пользователя 123 и пользователем 1. 
Пытаюсь написать запрос для получения диалогов например пользователя 2. Использую такой запрос, но он выдаёт лишние таблицы:

```
show TABLEs LIKE 'dialog%2%'
```

На этот запрос он выдаёт:

```
dialog_123_1
dialog_123_2
dialog_1_123456
dialog_2_1
```

Comment: Вы нарушили правила проектирования базы данных, вынесли внешний ключ из данных вообще в DDL в название таблицы, где этих данных не должно быть. А теперь жалуетесь, что в СУБД нет инструментов для работы с такой схемой? Да, их нет, SQL (по крайней мере в реализации MySQL) не предназначен для работы в таком режиме.

Comment: какие будут рекомендации?

Comment: Создать одну таблицу dialogs, с двумя ключами from_id и to_id, в которых хранить идентификаторы пользователей, участвующих в диалоге.

Comment: Делается одна таблица dialog и в ней кроме того, что есть сейчас, еще ID пользователя (который берется из таблицы пользователей). Причем именно ID, а не логин

Comment: Очень рекомендую прочитать статью про нормализацию данных - https://habrahabr.ru/post/254773/ а также "Как работает реляционная БД" - https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/266811/

Answer (score 2):

Проектирование такой реляционной базы данных, как заметил cheops - это неправильно. Просто представьте, сколько у Вас может быть таблиц, какая сложная будет работа с данными и как это скажется на скорости. Нормализуйте Вашу базу данных и в самом простом варианте храните диалоги в одной таблице.

Если не обращать внимания на правильность конструирования данной базы, то для решения подобной задачи в MySQL требуется использовать следующую конструкцию, в которой задействованы регулярные выражения:

```
 SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_названиеБазы REGEXP "_IdПользователя(_|$)+"
```

Подставьте название вашей базы данных и id пользователя. Пример:

```
 SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_chat REGEXP "_2(_|$){1}"
```

После выполнения запроса, будут выведены все таблицы попадающие под условие регулярного выражения.